# Can't use array key in the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$args = array(
  'n' => 10,
  'd' => $args['n']*3,
);
```

`Notice: Undefined variable: args in ...`

Why I can't do sth like that?

**Edit:**
So should I do this?

```
$args = array(
  'n' => 10,
);
$args = array(
  'd' => $args['n']*3,
);
```

It's kinda awful :P

Comment: You are calling the array before declaring it.

Comment: What Ronak Patel sad, the solution would be to save the 10 in a variable then set it to n and then multiply it by 3 and set it to d.

Comment: Do like this : `$args = array( 'n' => 10 );
$args['d'] = $args['n'] * 3;`

Answer (score 0):

It's a chicken/egg problem:

```
$args = array(...);
```

only returns and puts the new array into $args after the ENTIRE array definition has been parsed executed. So when you try to access $args within its own array definition, it won't be defined yet.

```
$args = array(0 => $args);
                   ^^^^^--undefined variable, not yet available for use.
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP first has to create the entire array, and only then can it assign the result to the $args property. This means that, while the array is being created, the value of $args is not yet set (or is whatever it was previously).

You either have to set the elements one at a time:

```
$args = array( 'n' => 10 );
$args['d'] = $args['n'] * 3;
```

Or do the calculation manually:

```
$args = array( 'n' => 10, 'd' => 10 * 3 );
```

Or like this:

```
$a = 10;
$args = array( 'n' => $a, 'd' => $a * 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the undefined variable error because `$args` is not defined at the point when you are trying to use it inside the array. You can get around this problem with a temporary variable:

```
$args = array(
  'n' => ($n = 10),
  'd' => $n * 3
);
```